# How to format a single column without mapping each column with withMapping?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I want to format one of the columns which is a date column (as a string) to another format.

The solution I found was to use `withMapping`:

```
class ModelExcelExport implements FromCollection, WithColumnFormatting, withMapping
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Model::select('id','email','date')->get();
    }

    public function map($model): array
    {
        return [
            $model->id,
            $model->email,
            \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::stringToExcel($model->date),
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
           'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY,
        ];
    }
}
```

But for that to work I have to map all of the columns, even if some of them do not need any formatting.

In my case there are many more columns (Not just 3 like in the example) so it's cumbersome to copy each and every column to the `map()` method just because I need a single column (the `date` column) to be in another format.

When I only place the `date` column in the `map()` it will not work:

```
public function map($model): array
{
    return [
        \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::stringToExcel($model->date)
    ];
}
```

Comment: you can ->selectRaw from eloquent changing the format via SQL query. If i've understood the question

Comment: Yes this is what's currently being used and it's working, but some people preferred to try the package's built-in methods (No idea why if the raw query + format works..)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best answer, but in order to map one single column you can do that using laravel built-in collection map method

```php
class ModelExcelExport implements FromCollection, WithColumnFormatting, withMapping
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Model::select('id','email','date')->get()->map(function($item) {
             $item->date = $item->format('dmY'); // formatting date using Carbon

             return $item;
        });
    }
}
```